# Is a cartomancer restricted to the hexes listed as complementing the archetype?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, archetype, witch

> Hexes: The following witch hexes complement the cartomancer archetype: evil eye, fortune, misfortune, soothsayer.
>
> Major Hexes: The following major hexes complement the cartomancer archetype: harrowing curse (see below), vision.
>
> Grand Hexes: The following grand hex complements the cartomancer archetype: Dire Prophecy.

from [d20pfsrd.com](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/witch/archetypes/paizo-witch-archetypes/cartomancer-witch-archetype)

Does the the quote mean that a Cartomancer has to choose between those restricted set of hexes?

Answer (score 8):

### No, they're just suggestions

The hexes are suggested as "complementing" the archetype, meaning that they work well with the modified class, either mechanically or thematically. However, they're just suggestions - you're free to choose other hexes if you like.

Comment: You may want to mention other instances where the Paizo devs write options the complement a certain archetype (e.g. barbarian archetypes and rage powers). May also want to mention that we don't know the exact method the devs use to select these options (e.g. flavor versus mechanical synergy)

Answer (score 2):

### They are not restricted to just those hexes

I have asked this [same question](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2umq9?What-is-the-purpose-of-abilities-that#1) at paizo messageboards. I was told by several community members that those are merely author suggestions to that archetype, as if the author was saying *"hey, these are good options for you"*.

However, I found **no official clarification** from the developers about that. Which leaves us with the definition of the word [complement](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/complement) to base ourselves on, which is what those people were telling me, those abilities will *complement my archetype and make it better*, but considering that some of those options are actually *bad* (especially for rage powers), take that with a grain of salt. Instead, consider that those options are **thematically fitting** for your archetype.

The [Totem Warrior](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/Barbarian/archetypes/paizo-barbarian-archetypes/totem-warrior) barbarian archetype, for instance, does absolutely *nothing* to the base class, as pointed out in a [FAQ](http://paizo.com/community/blog/v5748dyo5ldw0?The-FAQ-That-Time-Forgot). But it was [clarified by the developer team](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2nv2f?Totem-Warrior-Archetype-are-there-any-benefits#13) that this was merely a way to list their options (rage totems) in one place. So, you could simply assume that those *complements* are there so you don't build your character and only later find out that you had those options and be frustrated about it, especially considering that some of those lists are from multiple books.